# Graphs used in Sleep Cycle iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, frameworks, ios-frameworks

Does anybody know what graph framework/api/etc. the developers of the Sleep Cycle app (`http://mdlabs.se/sleepcycle/`) used in their application?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/ I would say,unless it's custom implementation. BTW, rolling your own custom graphs is pretty simple.

Comment: I thought of that, except on core-plot's page where they list which apps use core-plot, Sleep Cycle is not there.  Sleep Cycle is a pretty popular app, and I would not expect them to omit it

Comment: Must be something else then or custom. Another option is to modify core plot to suit your needs...